# OSGi EventAdmin

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm new in OSGi technology, and I have problems with Events. My application waits until 6:00pm and the server bundle sends a message to the client bundle. So I made some research and I found that it can be done withe EventAdmin:

1. How can I add EventAdmin to Eclipse (I'm using eclipse 3.8.1 ubuntu) ?
2. How do I use EventAdmin?
3. How can I send data with the event if it's possible?

NB: If it's possible to have a code example I will be glad.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can found sample for

Producer:

https://github.com/robertcsakany/welcometoosgi/tree/master/hu.blackbelt.welcometoosgi.eventproducer

```java
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.*;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.osgi.service.event.Event;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;

@Component(metatype = true, immediate = true)
@Properties(value = {
        @Property(name = "fooBar", value = "bar")
})
public class EventProducer {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventProducer.class);

    private String foo = "";

    @Reference
    EventAdmin eventAdmin;

    @Activate
    public void activate(ComponentContext context) {
        Dictionary properties = new Hashtable();
        properties.put("test", context.getProperties().get("fooBar"));
        Event generatedEvent = new Event("test/event/GENERATED", properties);
        log.info("Sending event");
        eventAdmin.sendEvent(generatedEvent);
    }
}
```

and for consumer:

https://github.com/robertcsakany/welcometoosgi/tree/master/hu.blackbelt.welcometoosgi.eventconsumer

```java
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.*;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.event.Event;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventConstants;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


@Component(metatype = true, immediate = true)
@Service
@Properties(value = {
        @Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, value = {"test/event/GENERATED"})
})
public class EventConsumer implements EventHandler {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventConsumer.class);

    private String foo = "";

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        log.info("Event catched - "+event.getTopic());
        log.info("Event property - "+event.getProperty("test"));
    }
}
```

Thats using declarative service to reference for other services from service tracker

Answer (score 2):

You can find a basic example in the [OSGi enRoute service catalog](http://enroute.osgi.org/services/org.osgi.service.event.html).

An example that heavily uses the Event Admin and is time based is the enRoute scheduler in the [OSGi enRoute examples](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.examples/tree/master/osgi.enroute.examples.scheduler.application)

About how to add it ... well that depends on what you're development environment is. In bndtools it is quite easy and should be clear if you follow the [OSGi enRoute Quick Start tutorial](http://enroute.osgi.org/book/200-quick-start.html)

Comment: First and third links are dead :(

Answer (score 0):

As you're using eclipse 3.8.1 with no dependency injection support, you may use the following code.

**Event listening.**
Implement org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler interface to handle events.
Register your listener in BundleContext. There is an example in [javadoc](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v41/org/osgi/service/event/EventHandler.html):

```
String[] topics = new String[{EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC,«com/sample_topic»};
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put(EVENT_TOPIC, topics);
context.registerService(EventHandler.class.getName(), this, ht);
```

**Event sending.**
EventAdmin instance can be used to send events. For details please see [javadoc](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/event/EventAdmin.html).
This interface provide us with 2 methods sendEvent for synchronous sending and postEvent for asynchronous sending.
You can obtain EventAdmin instance from BundleContext:

```
ServiceReference<EventAdmin> serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(EventAdmin.class);
EventAdmin eventAdmin = bundleContext.getService(serviceReference);
```

Equinox implementation of EventAdmin is very specific and I wrote a short [post about that](https://nickolaylaptev.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/equinox-eventadmin-why-not/).